# Blender script: Blender crashes when opening second file

Tags: scripting

I want to make a script that opens blender files one by one and modifies them. But when it's time to open the second file Blender crashes. Here is my code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    bpy.app.timers.register(open_file, first_interval=7)


def open_file():
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="path_of_my_file")


bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)


bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="path_of_my_file")
```

Comment: Why are you trying to load the file based on a timer? Even if that wouldn't crash, this is most likely not the right way to do what you're attempting to do. Why don't you open the second file once you're done processing the first?

Comment: As far as I can tell the crash happens because there's no window context when the timer is executed . See: https://developer.blender.org/T62074